# Queueable Apex in a Before Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, queueable-apex, asynchronous-testing

I am attempting to create logic that, on Contact record insert or update, will compare the Phone value of the record to another reference object and conditionally populate a checkbox as a result of the comparison.

The first iteration passed unit and functional testing, but was found to cause Apex CPU timeouts under high volume. Therefore, I made the class queueable.

After converting the class, I am now in a situation where testing in the UI works as desired/expected but each unit test returns this error: `System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []` here `Class.CellPhoneIndentifier.execute: line 91, column 1`

There isn't too much out there on same record update in a before trigger insert/update using queueable Apex, but [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MNEOIA4) seems to indicate this whole approach should not work and that I should be working on Ids instead of SObjects as in a future method.

So I'm confused as to why the UI works, but the tests don't and also why current logic appears to work at all when it apparently shouldn't.

```
     public class CellPhoneIndentifier implements Queueable  {

    --trimmed--

        public CellPhoneIndentifier (List<Contact> contactList, Map<Id, Contact> oldMap) {
            this.contactList = contactList;
            this.oldMap = oldMap;
        }


        public void execute (QueueableContext context) {    

    --trimmed--

            //Loop through contacts to check and see if they are in the mobile contact list
            for (Contact cont : contactsToCheck) {
                if(mobileContact.contains(cont) && cont.Preferred_Phone_is_Mobile__c == false) {
                    cont.Preferred_Phone_is_Mobile__c = true;
                    contactsToUpdate.add(cont);
                } else if (!mobileContact.contains(cont) && cont.Preferred_Phone_is_Mobile__c == true) {
                    cont.Preferred_Phone_is_Mobile__c = false;
                    contactsToUpdate.add(cont);
                }
            }

            update contactsToUpdate;
        }

--trimmed--
```

@isTest
public class CellPhoneIdentifierTest  {

```
//Get Household recordtype ids
static Id contactHouseholdTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Household').getRecordTypeId();

@TestSetup
static void setup() {

    Cellphone_Reference__c wirelessId = new Cellphone_Reference__c(Wireless_Block_Identifier__c = '9206430');
    insert wirelessId;

    List<Contact> testContacts = new List<Contact>();

    Contact nonCellContact = new Contact(LastName = 'nonCellContact',
                                    HomePhone = '920-247-2477',
                                    rC_Bios__Preferred_Phone__c = 'Home',
                                    RecordTypeId = contactHouseholdTypeId);

    testContacts.add(nonCellContact);

    Contact cellContact = new Contact(LastName = 'cellContact',
                            HomePhone = '920-643-0489',
                            rC_Bios__Preferred_Phone__c = 'Home',
                            RecordTypeId = contactHouseholdTypeId);

    testContacts.add(cellContact);

    Contact shortContact = new Contact(LastName = 'shortContact',
                                        HomePhone = '920-6',
                                        rC_Bios__Preferred_Phone__c = 'Home',
                                        RecordTypeId = contactHouseholdTypeId);

    testContacts.add(shortContact);

    Contact nophoneContact = new Contact(LastName = 'nophoneContact',
                                        RecordTypeId = contactHouseholdTypeId);

    testContacts.add(nophoneContact);

    insert testContacts;
}

//Tests a Cell contact being inserted
@isTest
static void insertCell() {
    Contact contactInsert = new Contact(LastName = 'TestContact',
                                    HomePhone = '920-643-0489',
                                    rC_Bios__Preferred_Phone__c = 'Home',
                                    RecordTypeId = contactHouseholdTypeId);

    Test.startTest();

    insert contactInsert;

    Test.stopTest();

    contactInsert = [SELECT Id, Phone, Preferred_Phone_is_Mobile__c FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'TestContact'];

    System.assertEquals(true,contactInsert.Preferred_Phone_is_Mobile__c);
}
--trimmed--
```

Comment: Justin -- (1) too much code here -- leave only the testmethod that fails; use  [edit] and identify the line of failure; (2) in `@TestSetup` - do you gate these DML to avoid invoking the queueable and then re-enable the queueable upon conclusion of `@TestSetup` (3) In general, queueable constructor should be passed values that can't change between enqueuing and execution so the first arg should be a set<Id> contactIds. But that won't be your issue here

Comment: Thank you - (1) I added clarification that every test method is failing and added the line of failure. As all are failing, is still worth removing some methods just so it isn't such a huge block? (2) I am not gating the DML in @TestSetup - what would that entail? (3) This is also something I need to understand more - in what scenarios is it ok to take advantage of Queueable's able to take SObjects?

Comment: (1) to get the most from the community, you want to show only the minimum necessary to reproduce the issue; see [ask].  Code dumps not recommended (2) Have some static vbl in the enqueuer class that is `@TestVisible` that you can turn on/off in testmethod; (3) Your second arg (map<id,sobject> is a good example of why sobject passing is relevant as old value can't change when queueable executes. Or, if you are doing a callout in queueable and the values of the sobject as of the moment of enequeuing should be used in the callout

Comment: (1) Totally get that though it can be tough knowing what to edit when lacking true understanding of the problem- tried to be more ruthless with the edits this time. (2) got it, makes sense. (3) Very helpful clarification, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a *before insert* trigger, there are no record Ids assigned yet. If you're testing in the UI, try creating a new record, it should have the same error (but it won't be visible in the UI since it is asynchronous). You can move the logic to after insert/after update to avoid this problem.

Comment: This was very helpful - I ended with after insert/update logic along with a check to avoid recursion. It's clear now why asynchronous triggered actions on the same record belong in the after context.